# Pegar apenas os valores antes do caracter "=" utilizando expressão regular?

Tags: delphi, string, regex

Tenho um arquivo contendo o seguinte conteúdo:

```
Maringa=123123
Marialva=789789
Mandaguacu=123456
Cidadex=A341a2
```

Como faço para pegar apenas os caracteres antes do `=`, utilizando expressão regular?

Tentei da seguinte maneira: `.*=`
Mas ai a String vem com o char igual (=), gostaria de poder negar esse char.

Comment: Que linguagem você está usando?

Comment: Que linguagem de programação você está usando? Diferentes linguagens de programação implementam regexes com sintaxes um pouco distintas.

Comment: Eu estava precisando para Delphi, deu certo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Você pode capturar grupos da regex depois de fazer o match. Exemplo:

```
(\w+)=(\w+)
```

Assim o primeiro grupo será o seu identificador e o segundo será o valor.

Se ainda preferir fazer uma regex que só reconheça o identificador você pode usar:

```
\w+(?==)
```

`(?=algo)` é chamado de "positive lookahead". É uma forma de olhar o texto seguinte e confirmar se ele é `algo`. Se não for, falhe. Se for, aceite a regex, mas não o inclua no resultado. Existe outras variantes como o "negative lookahead" `(?!algo)` que faz o oposto. Note que nem toda biblioteca de expressões regulares suporta esse tipo de sintaxe.

Comment: Muito obrigado, a segunda opção deu certo. Porém não entendi muito o que foi feito, poderia dar uma breve explicação?

Comment: @fymoribe lookahead é uma expressão que precisa ser casada mas que não é considerado como parte do padrão casado, para propósitos de extração/substituição.

Comment: @fymoribe Adicionei um pouco mais de detalhes.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal muito obrigado pela explicação, deu certo a implementação.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal No caso o igual é um token para qualquer coisa? Não seria correto usar `w` no caso?

Comment: @Victor, não entendi a pergunta. No caso `\w+(?==)` vai procurar por uma palavra `\w+` que seja seguida por um igual `(?==)`. Se fosse seguida por uma seta, por exemplo, seria `(?=->)`.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Entendi! No caso eu estava entendendo o `?=` como um `=` opcional, não sabia da existencia e não tinha entendido o lookahead.

Answer (score 13):

Use `^[^=]*`, que vai reconhecer uma sequência ininterrupta de caracteres diferentes de `=` no início da linha. Por partes:

- `^`: reconhece o início da linha;
- `[^=]`: reconhece um caractere diferente de `=` (no início de uma expressão com colchetes, o acento circunflexo, `^`, representa negação);
- `*`: reconhece a expressão anterior (`[^=]`) o máximo possível de vezes.

Sem a primeira parte (`^`), a expressão regular produz dois resultados: o texto antes do `=` e o texto depois do `=`. Se você estiver executando a expressão regular a cada linha e pegando apenas o primeiro resultado, o `^` do início é opcional e a expressão pode ser simplificada para `[^=]*`.

Comment: Eu tinha respondido `[^=]*`, mas apaguei minha resposta por achar que a pergunta na verdade é outra: "Mas ai a String vem com o char igual (=), gostaria de poder negar esse char"

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, próxima vez tento escrever melhor a minha pergunta.

Comment: @fymoribe Se você acha que pode deixar esta pergunta mais clara, por favor edite (tem um link "editar" abaixo da pergunta). Essa pergunta pode ser útil para muitas pessoas no futuro

Comment: @bfavaretto, na verdade `[^=]*` não traz o char igual (=).

Comment: @rodrigorgs Vou me abster, regex nao é o meu forte.

Comment: Essa resposta merece mais votos, não pq a outra resposta seria errada, mas pq essa resposta funciona na maioria das variações de regex e ensina um padrão geral que pode utilizar para problemas semelhantes (nem todas variações tem o \w...).

Answer (score 2):

Dependendo do que você deseja fazer, talvez seja melhor usar o `split` para quebrar a string em duas.

Em javascript:

```
var linha     = "Maringa=123123";
var resultado = linha.split("=');
```

`$resultado` agora é um array contendo `['Maringa', '123123']`;